# How to filter by answered questions?

Tags: support, meta

I put this into the search but it returned 0 results:

```
how to filter by answered questions
```

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: thanks for the downvotes.  It's Friday - there should be more.

Comment: wut? votes there don't affect your rep, don't worry.

Comment: I disagree on that.   +4 on answer with a question that is downvoted.  Stackoverflow weirdness as usual.

Answer (score 6):

Just search for

```
answers:1
```

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A1

Comment: where do you put your actual search string?

Comment: @4th search bar at top-right.

Comment: @4tth - Where you always search, like `[sql] title:injection answers:2`

Comment: ugh!  where do you put answers:1 than?  I guess its like [search term] answers:1

Comment: answers:1 means at least 1 answer right?

Comment: Yeah; just hit "Enter" in the search box, then click the "Advance Search Tips" for all the goodies

Comment: Here is the full page for [how to search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)